# Selected List element color change with angular directive

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a directive that should make list element to be red color on click. It is working as expected but it should also
Turn to black when other li is clicked so only the selected li should be in red color

Here is my implementation,

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) clickedInside(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.removeBorder();
      this.setElementStyleToBold();
      if (this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
        this.clicked = event.target.id;
      }
}
```

Here is another host listener that watch the click outside and change the color to black when clicked on the document,

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) clickedOutside(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.removeBorder();
}
```

In the clickedInside function I am calling remove border function before calling setElementStyleToBold function so it will remove the black color and red color is applied only on the selected item.

This is not working as intended and I don’t know where I was wrong
Here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwsk33?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) on stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new method with below code

```
private removeColor() {
      document.querySelectorAll('[appSelectedItem]').forEach((el) => {
        this.removeBorder(el);
      })
    }
```

and call that instead of `this.removeBorder();` in `clickedInside` method like this

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event']) clickedInside(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.removeColor();
      this.setElementStyleToBold();
      if (this.el.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
        this.clicked = event.target.id;
      }
}
```

Comment: Its not the angular way of using document.querySelectorAll. Can you make it in angular way?

Comment: You can inject document in angular and then use that document element. I have updated code for injecting document on stackblitz

Comment: I want to get the UL without the document.

Comment: you can get that by `this.el.nativeElement.parentElement` without document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197930/discussion-between-kinjal-and-anonymous).

Comment: Please let me know a way where we can use this without Document .

Comment: I already upvoted your question but it should work without the document.